# Given 4 line equation (6 intersection), find the 4 vertex that form a convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

> Given 4 line equation (6 intersection), find the 4 vertex that form a convex quadrilateral

It is guaranteed that a convex quadrilateral existed. How can I find which four intersection point form the quadrilateral. Preferably avoid combinatorial search

**Example**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I begin, it is important to note that I will be working in Euclidean geometry.

To determine which intersections form the quadrilateral, let's begin by slowly building up our structure by adding line by line. I will denote lines by $L_1, L_2, L_3$, and $L_4$, and the vertex given by the intersection of $L_i$ and $L_j$ by $(ij)$.

First, we note two observations based on the restriction that six intersections must occur.

1. No two lines are parallel.
2. No set of three lines share an intersection.

To start, add two lines, $L_1$ and $L_2$, and by (1), they intersect at $(12)$. Add $L_3$. By $(2)$, the intersections $(13)$ and $(23)$ form a triangle $T$ with the vertices $(12),(13),(23)$. I will be visualizing $L_3$ as the base of the triangle from here on out, with $L_1$ as the "left" side and $L_2$ as the "right" side. Now, we add $L_4$. There are two cases here, where $L_4$ either pierces $T$ or not.

**Case 1:** If $L_4$ pierces $T$, we may assume without any loss of generality that $L_4$ passes through the sides $\overline{(12)(23)}$ and $\overline{(12)(13)}$. This yields the quadrilateral with vertices $(14),(24),(13),(23)$.

**Case 2:** If $L_4$ does not pierce $T$, then consider the intersections $(34)$ and $(24)$. We can assume WLOG that $(14)$ does not lie on the segment $\overline{(24)(34)}$. Hence, this creates a quadrilateral with vertices $(12),(23),(24),(34)$.

You should try and show that these quadrilaterals are indeed convex!